# How to create a object keys and values dynamically in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a date dropdown start date and end date. Displaying date as below format

```
startDate:date="202035";
ednDate:date="202037";
```

Based on two date I want to build below object dynamically with date key and value(default zero) .
e.g.

```
var result= {
            "202035": 0,
            "202036": 0,
            "202037": 0
        };
```

I did something like this but cannot loop with date?
var selectedStartDate = startDate;
result={ [selectedStartDate]: 0 };

Comment: Do you mean the results is object type and you can't loop with date inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple javascript method.

```js
const returnObj = {};
const startDate = { date: "202035"};
const endDate = {date: "202037"};
for(index = Number(startDate.date); index <= Number(endDate.date); index++) {
  returnObj[index.toString()] = 0;
}
console.log(returnObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const startDate="202035";
const endDate="202037";

let startDateInInt = parseInt(startDate, 10)
const endDateInInt = parseInt(endDate, 10)

let endResult = {};
while(startDateInInt <= endDateInInt) {
  endResult[startDateInInt] = 0
  startDateInInt++;
}


console.log(endResult)
```

Not sure sure if this is what you want in mind, basically looping it and assigning it to an object

Comment: Whats the differecne between this and my solution?

Comment: Maybe an extra description is what OP really needed? I've no idea man lol @Nitheesh